# JBOSS JMS Clustering DB replication

Tags: java, jboss, jms, cluster-computing

I was doing JMS clstering. I was successful in doing HASingleton JMS clustering failover. But 1 thing encouter was the they need to share same database for persistance. cannot we have seperate database and replicate through jms or jgroups.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: There are two different concepts:Database clustering and Application clustering. Which do you want? Or both?

Comment: JMS stores transaction details/data peristance in its DB. How do I make secure the second node recieves this as well. Otherwise JMS clustering will be ineffictive as the second node JMS will not have same peristance data in its DB. Actually I am implementing a failover stratergy, in this if first node is down, there is high probability the it db is also down. Can JMSclustering take care of replicating persisted data to second node, In HASingleton JMS clustering. We dont want to use a shared db for same

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using JBoss AS 5.x or 4.3, which uses JBoss Messaging as the JMS implementation. For JBoss Messaging, you'll have a single database configuration to store your messages. This, AFAIK, cannot be changed. What you *can* do is to also use a clustered database (like MySQL Cluster or Oracle RAC), and then configure JBoss Messaging to use it. This way, you have HA in the database-side as well.

Comment: JMS stores transaction details/data peristance in its DB. How do I make secure the second node recieves this as well. Otherwise JMS clustering will be ineffictive as the second node JMS will not have same peristance data in its DB. Actually I am implementing a failover stratergy, in this if first node is down, there is high probability the it db is also down. Can JMSclustering take care of replicating persisted data to second node, In HASingleton JMS clustering. We dont want to use a shared db for same

Comment: The same database is used for both nodes. They both persist to the same tables, just using a different "nodeId". If one fails, the other detects this and takes care of the messages assigned to the node that failed. So, the data is already being replicated, but at the DB level. This is how it works for JBoss Messaging, and it's an implementation detail.

Comment: i want to have 1 db for each, how do i achieve this

Comment: I don't think this is possible with JBoss Messaging.